# How can I know what versions of Windows I can legally use?

Tags: windows, downgrade, licensing

Bought an older laptop on the cheap for some light work.  Originally it came with Windows XP, the refurbisher put Windows 10 on it.  The computer works for what I need it to, but barely (system requirements for 10).

Where (online or by phone) can I look to see what versions of Windows that I can legally downgrade to?

Comment: I’m sorry but anything that originally came with XP is too old for any sensible work today. It’s a miracle Windows 10 even boots. Some lightweight Linux might work better.

Comment: @DanielB it's primarily for some document editing.  not much power needed there, as wordpad will work on text, rtf, and word documents.  I've not been wanting to throw linux on there as I want to know my options, direct from MS if possible.  Can't find anything from Dell about the licensing except originally it was XP.

Answer (score 2):

> Bought an older laptop on the cheap for some light work. Originally it came with Windows XP, the refurbisher put Windows 10 on it.

Downgrade rights are only granted by the original manufacturer.  If the machine came with Windows XP originally, then it does not have any downgrade rights, since Windows XP cannot be downgraded to any version of Windows.

> Is there anywhere I can look to see what versions of Windows that I can legally downgrade to?

It is not clear what type of Windows 10 license you have.  However, if it is a retail Windows 10 license, then you are not granted any downgrade rights.  If you want to run anything other than Windows XP or Windows 10 you will have to purchase a license to that version.

Answer (score -3):

Too many unanswered details. But *generally* speaking. If your Laptop *originally* came with XP. You can *usually* upgrade to most any *client* version of Windows, free of charge. My last statement depends upon 2 details.

- you have a `COA` (Certificate Of Authenticity) "sticker" on your Laptop. or,
- It came with an `OEM` copy "vendor preinstall"

Free often does *not* apply to (Windows) Server products.

In *both* cases you will need to have registered the Product(s) concerned.

"About (this version of) Windows", will give you some indication as to it's status, as well as where to get further information.

This answer is based in part on my upgrade of an OEM upgrade on my Dell Laptop from XP to Windows 7, then to Windows Windows 8.1. Both of which were free.

Comment: “You can usually upgrade to most any client version of Windows, free of charge.” - This isn’t true.  OEMs have only ever offered downgrade rights.  There isn’t even an upgrade path from Windows XP to Windows 10.

Comment: I based my reply in part on my upgrade of an OEM upgrade on my Dell Laptop from XP to Windows 7, then Windows Windows 8.1. Both of which were free. My answer is correct based on actual experience.